# Need help understanding full outer join

Tags: sql, db2

I want to use full outer join to join two tables with records (id, value). The two tables have no intersections on id field, but I want to join them by the id field. I am trying to use full outer join to accomplish this join but I don't understand how.

I am using DB2.

So far, I have (each statement executed by hand individually):

```
create table S1 (
    id integer primary key not null,
    value integer not null)

create table S2 (
    id integer primary key not null,
    value integer not null)

insert into S1 values (0, 50)
insert into S1 values (1, 20)

insert into S2 values (2, 40)
insert into S2 values (3, 90)

select * from S1 full outer join S2
```

I get an error on the full outer join attempt:

```
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "join S2" was found following "* from S1 full
outer".  Expected tokens may include:  "<space>".  SQLSTATE=42601
```

EDIT: Thanks! I got it working, but it is not what I expected.

```
select * from S1 full outer join S2 on S1.id = S2.id
```

the issue is that now it shows (: signifies space)

```
+--+-----+--+-----+
|ID|VALUE|ID|VALUE|
+--+-----+--+-----+
|-:|-::::|3:|90:::|
+--+-----+--+-----+
|-:|-::::|2:|40:::|
+--+-----+--+-----+
|1:|20:::|-:|-::::|
+--+-----+--+-----+
|0:|50:::|-:|-::::|
+--+-----+--+-----+
```

I did not want the duplicate fields. Is there a way to make the table join into a:

```
+--+-----+
|ID|VALUE|
+--+-----+
```

table?

I tried using

```
select id from s1
full outer join s2 on s1.id = s2.id
```

and needless to say, I get

```
SQL0203N  A reference to column "ID" is ambiguous.  SQLSTATE=42702
```

SOLVED!

```
select coalesce(s1.id, s2.id) as id, \
       coalesce (s1.value, s2.value) as value \
from s1 full outer join s2 on s1.id = s2.id and s1.value = s2.value  
group by id asc
```

and another solution from D Stanley (mofidied)

```
SELECT Id, Value \
FROM S1 \
UNION ALL \
SELECT Id, Value \ 
FROM S2 \
ORDER BY ID ASC
```

Thanks!

Comment: You still need to say what you are joining on. E.g. `ON s1.id = s2.id`. It is only a cross join that doesn't require the ON.

Comment: still need the on clause...adding "on 1 = 1" to the end of your query functionally creates a cross join for this

Comment: Thanks! That works, though now I have a formatting issue... Any help is appreciated!

Comment: @Dmitry that's a `UNION`, not a `JOIN`.  See my updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**New Answer**

Based on your updated question, you want a `UNION`, not a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT Id, Value
FROM S1
UNION ALL
SELECT Id, Value 
FROM S2
```

**Original answer**

You still need to have *some* criteria to join the tables.  If the IDs will *never* intersect you can just use

```
SELECT * 
FROM S1 
FULL OUTER JOIN S2 ON S1.id = S2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

FULL OUTER JOIN as other OUTER and INNER JOIN wants an ON clause after declaration of tables.

In this way:

```
SELECT *
FROM S1
FULL OUTER JOIN S2
ON S1.field = S2.field
```

Only JOIN without ON clause is CROSS JOIN (because implements Cartesian Product)

Comment: sorry for the snipe edit.  I was trying to edit my answer and hit the wrong one.